# Useradd Bash Script - Userscript: 13: Userscript: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create a Bash script that has some automation in order to create user accounts from a CSV file. I have the script finished and the code is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
########################
# User Creation Script #
########################
filein="users.csv"
IFS=$'\n'

if [ ! -f "$filein" ]
then
 echo "File $filein cannot be found"
else

groups=(`cut -d: -f 3 "$filein"`)
fullnames=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein"`)
userid=(`cut -d: -f 4 "$filein"`)
usernames=(`cut -d: -f 2 "$filein"`)

# Checks to see if group exists, if not then its created
for group in ${groups[*]}
do
 grep -q "^$group" /home/group ; let x=$?
if [ $x  -eq 1 ]
then
  groupadd "$group"
fi
done

# Creates the user account, adds them to the group, and sets the password
x=0
created=0
for user in ${usernames[*]}
do
useradd -n -c $fullnames[$x]} -g ${groups[$x]} $user 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  let created=$created+1
fi

echo "${userid[$x]}" | passwd -stdin "$user" > /dev/null

# Sends the user a mail message
echo "Your Acccount has been created! Your username is $user andyour      
temp password is \"$password\" without the quotes."
| mail -s "New Account for $user" -b root $user
x=$x+1
 echo -n "..."
  sleep .20
 done
  sleep .20
 echo " "
 echo "Complete. $created Accounts have been created."
fi
```

When I go to run it in the terminal I get this error:

> Userscript: 13: Userscript: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting
>   "then")

I'm currently in a Linux System Administration course and all of this is new to me.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus I owe you a beer!

Comment: Don't use `cut` to parse the fields.  `while IFS=: read fullnames usernames group userid ; do .... done < users.csv` will loop through each line assigning the variables per the columns in the file.

Comment: `expecting "then"`? really? Ignoring the lack of indenting, the only thing I actually see would be syntactically wrong is the pipe at the start of the line (and my versions of Bash complain about exactly that.) The if statement at the beginning of the script looks to have all parts intact, especially the `then`. Unless there's some invisible character that doesn't copypaste correctly from the text here in this Q.